# How to join related objects and render them in template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-orm

I have tow related models:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My problem is how to list all polls along with their respective choices in the template.

The ORM query that I have right now is:

```
polls = Choice.objects.select_related('poll')
```

And in template:

```
{% for p in polls %}

 <li>{{p.choice_text}}</li> 

{% endfor %}
```

But this solution only lists the choices. What I want is to render choices related to each poll. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that `select_related('poll')` on `Choice` doesn't return `polls`, it's just fetching all `poll` information in one underlying sql query. Check django doc for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queryset:

```
polls = Polls.objects.all() # Give you all polls
```

Template :

```
{% for p in polls %}
    <p>Poll :{{ p.title }}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for choice in p.choice_set.all %}
       <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this will help you, if I understand your question

Comment: Fantastic! As usual, django can do it much simpler than I'd thought. Just need a little edit. In template it should be `{{p.ttiel}}` and `{{choice.choice_text}}` otherwise it shows just `object`.

Comment: Done, it was just for example. You can display what you want of course :)

Comment: where should I put the queryset?

Comment: @Leila In your view, and pass the variable with the queryset result in your context. Like this, your result will be pass to your template.